# How to show pager in terms of views of tags?

Tags: 7

I've lists of tags suppose **good** and **bad**, now when I click to good tag it lists all good posts ( full posts ). But I wanted to show good posts only upto 5 items then all other should be there while I navigate.

So, how can I show the pager for the clicked tags. I tried it with views module, but nowhere I could see it to do this.

I've setup my views like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of how you setup your view?

Comment: @PontusNilsson updated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to check the checkbox "Use a pager"?

Comment: @PontusNilsson That pager is for tags itself(how many tags should be displayed). But I wanted to show pager when I click to the tags.

Comment: Create a view of content with pager and pass the term id as contextual filter.

Comment: @wolverine could you please add the pictures to do the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view of content ( as a page with pager ) and add a contextual filter named `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`. Refer the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once you have configured this then you can acces this view using a url like `mysite.com/view-path/tag-name`.

Comment: Is that in 7? I can't see that.

Comment: Yes, else you can follow the answer provided by @Bhuvana. Which will be easy for you.

Comment: Her answer is correct and views provide a view to list content based on taxonomy term.

Comment: and is the second image for tags view?

Comment: all the images are for the single contextual filter that you create.

Comment: all for content pager? and what to do in taxonomy terms views?

Comment: You display the term name and rewrite the result to create a link to the content view like `content-view-path/[term-name-token]`

Comment: all steps as per the images I did but couldn't get.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15153/discussion-between-wolverine-and-navin-rauniyar).

Comment: The last step I was modifying was not working and by removing and adding again worked fine. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I think you could answer this question. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118689/how-to-show-view-item-by-trimming

Answer (score 0):

Views module provides a view for Taxonomy terms to cater to the requirement of displaying articles related to a tag.

Under Structure -> Views look for the view "Taxonomy term" and enable it in case it is disabled. You do not need to create a view for this purpose.
[image]

The taxonomy page by default has the pager configured with 10 items per page.You may edit it by clicking on the edit option of the view and editing the pager option as shown in the screenshot here. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you Bhuvana for your reply, but that's not what I wanted.