# How to show view item by trimming?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to show articles by trimming. So, first I tried it by managing the display of body field to trimmed from content type. After fail to get desired results I tried it with views module by adding a contextual filter **Content: Body** setting character limit to 200 but did nothing.

[image]

I would like to hear the answer from this module as I also have the contextual filter: **Content: Has taxonomy term ID** already in this view.

---

> **Update:**

**I want to add a view of taxonomy terms where I have created a view with contextual filter previously to which taxonomy term name is linked in this view:**

[image]

In which taxonomy term is there:

[image]

And I tried with  `Trim this field to a maximum length` too but couldn't success.

Comment: If you want to display this filed then why are you trimming this in contextual filter, it conflicting your statement. If you want to display it, then use "Rewrite results" feature but first confirm what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I just wanted to trim the articles for this view. And in rewrite results there is no trimming option.

Comment: Sorry but still I am not clear. Do you want to use trimmed text in contextual filter or in output of this view as a field. Please be specific this time, either you want to use body field in contextual filter or in Fields to display in frontend on page.

Comment: trim for output of this view.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get anywhere triiming in a contextual filter, you need to click on the field and use the rewrite results fieldset in your fields settings.

[image]

Simply enter a maximum length, and choose extras like an ellipsis "..." to text that is cut off.

You may also need to change the format to plain text. Or choose a trimmed format.

[image]

Comment: Oops! I didn't see that. Thank you. But When I tried it nothing happened.

Comment: You may also need to set the text to display as plain text. On the same menu as the picture, but above. If there is any formatting, like paragraphs, it may not be trimming correctly.

Comment: where is it **text to display as plain text** ? I couldn't see.

Comment: please see updated answer for new pic

Comment: I couldn't see formatter as I'm using taxonomy term in field view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of option here for trimming the body.

If you use **option 2** and dispaly body as default text Formatter then better to enable  `Field can contain HTML` option that ensure tags are properly closed after trimming.

[image]

For term field in taxonomy term view:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying this to add field and configure? If so, I don't see such option as I added the field **Taxonomy term: Name** and even couldn't see to add another field with Content: body option.

Comment: Why are you confusing us, just describe your exact problem statement first. In this way we are unable to help you, which field you want to display from which content type or taxonomy at least describe this in proper manner. Then ask further question, edit your original post and described your problem statement in more elaborate way. even also removed your screenshot because it is making more conflict here.

Comment: please check my update.

Comment: I also edited my answer as I understood from your updated question. "Trim this field to a maximum length" Taxonomy term name or something else. Not sure but edited my post over there.

Comment: I already tried that but nothing happened.

Comment: Oops! That trims the tags itself as I check it with value 2 it was trimming tags itself not article of clicked tag.

Comment: So, I think it must be in other view i.e. in contextual filter...

Comment: @Navin Rauniyar I beleive you are following up with your [previous question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118526/how-to-show-pager-in-terms-of-views-of-tags/118537#118537). If so and you want to trim the content, then you have to do it in content view not the tag view.

Comment: @wolverine Yes you are right (previous question). Can we have a chat on this?

Comment: @wolverine could you please answer on this?